# mongodb stream change when updating sub-field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB 4.4.10 and pymongo 4.6.0

When updating a subfield of a document, namely `"configuration.requested_state"`, by doing this:

```
result = await self._collection.update_one(
    {"_id": ObjectId(my_id)}, {"$set": {"configuration.requested_state": state}}
)
```

While listeing for changes with this:

```
pipeline = [
            {
                "$match": {
                    "$or": [
                        {
                            "operationType": "update",
                            "updateDescription.updatedFields.configuration.requested_state": {
                                "$exists": True,
                            },
                        },
                        {"operationType": "insert"},
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

I don't get any update. Indeed, the document associated to this change is :

```
'updateDescription': {'updatedFields': {'configuration.requested_state': 'stopped'}}
```

which is hardly filterable, because the field `'configuration.requested_state'` contains a dot.

However, if I update the full `"configuration"`, not just `"configuration.requested_state"`, I get the expected update:

```
'updateDescription': {'updatedFields': {'configuration' : { 'requested_state': 'stopped'}}}
```

on which my pipeline's filter works. But this is not acceptable because it means pushing the whole document whereas I want to update only a subset.

Is there any way to build a pipeline with the filter for this update ? (i.e with a dot in the field's name)

Comment: I don't have a 4.4 server handy.  When I test with MongoDB 7.0 `db.uptest.updateOne({"configuration.requested_state":"new"},{$set:{configuration:{requested_state:"newest"}}})` results in a change object containing `updateDescription: {
      updatedFields: { configuration: { requested_state: 'newest' } },`.  Perhaps upgrading is the way to go?

Comment: @Joe , `{$set:{configuration:{requested_state:"newest"}` doesn't do the expected result, because it flushes the other fields of configuration and keeps only requested_state. Can you please test this in Mongo7: `{"$set": {"configuration.requested_state": "newest"}`

Comment: ah, my mistake, doing it that way does give the fieldname containing a dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB 5.0 introduces the [$getField](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/#-getfield--aggregation-) aggregation operator that can better handle field names with non-alphanumeric characters.

You can use $getField inside a match expressions by using the [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#-expr) query operator.

In the changestream pipeline below, the $getField operator is used to get the value of the field named 'configuration.requested_state' from the 'updatedFields' field in the change document, then '$gt' compares that with null.  Since null is (almost) the minimum value in the MongoDB [comparison/sort order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#comparison-sort-order) any values except 'null' and 'undefined' will match.

```
db.collection.watch([
   {$match:{$expr:{
        $gt:[null,
             {$getField: {
                input:"$updatedFields",
                field:"configuration.requested_state"
             }}
        ]
   }}}
])
```

Mongoplayground.net doesn't support changestreams, but here is an aggregation example showing that this pipeline can match the fieldname containing a dot:
[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GkwFrmMPGpW)

Comment: Thank you, indeed this solves the issue. So upgrading to Mongo 5+ is the way to go.