# mongodb trigger match expression for when property of nested object updated

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a `products` collection that contains objects with the following structure in mongo:

```
{
    "_id": "ABCDE12345",
    "storefronts": [
        {
            "_id": "XYZ123",
            "recalculatePrices": "2024-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00",
            ...other properties
        },
        {
            "_id": "XXX246",
            "recalculatePrices": "2024-01-02T00:00:00.000+00:00",
            ...other properties
        }
    ],
    ...other properties
}
```

I want a trigger to fire if any of the `recalculatePrices` values gets updated, is it possible to do this with a match expression?

Comment: It is possible with $getField, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77622553/2282634